# voice web based application Silverlight C# p2p

Tags: c#, silverlight, p2p, voice

I got a task to develop voice web based application in Silverlight. I would appreciate any help from those who have previous experince in programming voice application. Demands are - it should be p2p application (we are affraid of traffic > 1000 users can kill server) + lags should be < 100 ms.

Any idea where to start from?

Root.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Silverlight does not support p2p sockets, you need a server to use sockets.

The only way to do real p2p without a server would be an OOB app that calls native / full .net code. Since neither of those works on Mac, you would be better off starting with WPF.

The only way to use Sockets with SL in a cross-paltform way AFAIK requires a server.